# The grammar of these two sentences

Tags: verbs, sentence, subjects

Sentence 1:

'He noted his father was a nice guy.'

Sentence 2:

'He noted his father, as "a man with different attributes", was a nice guy.'

**May I say that:**

Sentence 1:

1. "He" is the subject of the sentence "He noted"?
2. "his father" is the subject of the sentence "his father was a nice guy."
3. "his father" is the object of the verb "noted"?

Sentence 2:

4. "He" is the subject of the sentence "He noted"?
5. "his father" is the subject of the sentence 'his father, as "a man with different attributes", was a nice guy.'?
6. "his father" is the object of the verb "noted"?
7. How can I call 'as "a man with different attributes"'?

Comment: Your points 1 and 2 both seem to referring to Sentence 1 - or is point 2 introducing a third sentence?

Comment: I edited to make my question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Sentence 1:'He noted his father was a nice guy.'
>
> Sentence 2:'He noted his father, as "a man with different attributes", was a nice guy.'
>
> May I say that:

> 1"He" is the subject of the sentence "He noted"?

Yes

> 2 "his father" is the subject of the sentence "his father was a nice guy."

No. it is the subject of the noun clause “[that] his father was a nice guy."

> 3 "his father" is the object of the verb "noted"?

No. The object of the verb "noted" is the noun clause (often called a “content clause”) “[that] his father was a nice guy."

Sentence 2:

> "He" is the subject of the sentence "He noted"?

No. it is the subject of “'He noted his father *[, as "a man with different attributes",]* was a nice guy.'”

> "his father" is the subject of the sentence 'his father, as "a man with different attributes", was a nice guy.'?

No. "his father" is the subject of the clause “[that] his father was a nice guy."

> "his father" is the object of the verb "noted"?

> 3 "his father" is the object of the verb "noted"?

No. The object of the verb "noted" is the noun clause (often called a “content clause”) “[that] his father was a nice guy."

<s>How can</s> **What  is the function of** 'as "a man with different attributes"'?

**As** is a preposition; “"a man with different attributes"” is a main clause acting as a noun. It is acting adjectivally on “his father”.